# Is OpenSsl available in Visual Studio in Windows OS?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, openssl, cryptography

> **Is OpenSsl available in Visual Studio in Windows OS ?**

I want to Encrypt some text using OpenSSL in Visual Studio 2017.

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaopenssl?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) in which it is said that OpenSSL is not Available in Windows ?

Then what is purpose of `System.Security.Cryptograpgy.Openssl` Nuget Packet in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is OpenSsl available in Visual Studio in Windows OS?

Yes, at least according to their [FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html) and their [available binaries.](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries)

> Then what is purpose of System.Security.Cryptograpgy.Openssl Nouget Packet in Visual Studio ?

Because of the, non-intuitive way(at least to me), Microsoft Documentation is laid out, it's often harder to understand **why** something exists/ is available.

Understanding **why** this particular package isn't immediately useful. We have to look at several sections of the Documentation page that you linked.

Under the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaopenssl?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) section we see

> The RSAOpenSsl class is an implementation of the RSA algorithm using OpenSSL. It isn't available on Windows and is only available on other operating systems when OpenSSL is installed. ...

This is important because it essentially tells us that this particular package doesn't work on windows and is meant to target specifically non-windows platforms.

This may seem pretty non-intuitive because C# and several frameworks that Microsoft develop such as .NET Framework explicitly **do not** target anything BUT Windows/Microsoft platforms. So to figure this out we have to look a little deeper, and in this case, WAY deeper into the web page(since it's so long).

If we scroll all the way to the bottom of the page we can see the '[Applies To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaopenssl?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#applies-to)' section that most Microsoft documentation pages include.

> | Product | Versions |
> | --- | --- |
> | .NET Core | 1.0, 1.1 |
> | .NET Platform Extensions | 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 5.0 |

This section, which is always inconveniently at the bottom of the page(even ridiculously long pages). It does describe though **what platforms this package targets**, which finally answers our question as to **why**.

This package specifically targets the .NET Core platform, which is one of Microsoft's frameworks that are cross-platform. Which means that not all packages and functions will work on all platforms.

Although you didn't explicitly ask, the above information naturally leads to a followup question of, if we can't use this package, how can we use OpenSSL then?

For that I would recommend using [their pre-compiled binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) that specifically target the platform you are targeting, which would appear to be a windows platform.